# why is area of a canvas being devided ?

Tags: divisibility, area

Hey guy i am not so great at math and basically i have the following calculation that i need to figure out the entire formula ,looks like below:

```
nb_particles = particles.nb * (canvas width *  canvas height / 1000) / density_area
```

My question pertains to a subset of the above formula, so i want to know what exactly does `canvas width *  canvas height / 1000` , do ?

basically `width * height` give use the `area` but what does devideing the area by 1000 give us ?? i am not quite getting this , what exactly is achieved here by deviding the area by 1000 ?

Comment: It is probably something to do with the units being used. Without more context it is hard to tell.

Comment: @almagest there is no set of exact units being used